# How to get html height in code behind?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, vb.net

I want to set the height of my "b" textbox and set it as my "a" height.

This is my current code for getting the height in code behind.

```
Dim a As TextBox = CType(e.Item.FindControl("txtNote1"), TextBox)
Dim b As TextBox = CType(e.Item.FindControl("txtNote2"), TextBox)

Dim aHeight as Integer =  a.Height.Value
b.Height = aHeight
```

But it returns 0px only. How can i get the html value if I did not set a static value for my textbox?

Comment: If the height of your textbox is dynamic or change on the client, the server won't know it because that value isn't sent to the server by default. Before doing a post back, you would have to make sure that the height value is set in a form element like a hidden input.

Comment: oh okay i understand now, but the question is, how will i get the height value and set in the the form element before doing a postback?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<asp:TextBox ID="a" runat="server" Height="30px"></asp:TextBox>  
<asp:TextBox ID="b" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

`code behind`

```
b.Height = a.Height.Value
```

Comment: Unfortunately, my textarea's height is blank. Because my height will be unpredictable, or should i say, dynamic

Answer (score 0):

You can set the height of the TextBoxes to `100%` and manipulate the `<div>` surrounding the TextBoxes using JavaScript for example. That way you don't need the exact height in code behind.

```
<div style="height:400px;" id="div_01">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="100%" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
</div>

<div style="height:200px;" id="div_02">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Height="100%" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("div_02").style.height = document.getElementById("div_01").style.height;
</script>
```